# Input elements having the same value with 'for' loop

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, dom

I have just been experimenting with JavaScript and was trying this code.

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
var n = elements.length; // Should be: 10

for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  elements[i].onclick = function () {
    console.log("This is element #" + i);
  };
}
```

```html
<p>Element: #1</p>
<p>Element: #2</p>
<p>Element: #3</p>
<p>Element: #4</p>
<p>Element: #5</p>
```

However, when the code is run, something weird occurs. Basically, for example, if you click on element #1, it will say that you've clicked on element #5.

---

This is what I am curious to know:

1. Why is this occurring?
2. Is there a fix for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the code below to correct the issues.

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
var n = elements.length;

function makeHandler(num) {
     return function() {
         console.log("This is element #" + num);
     };
};

for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    elements[i].onclick = makeHandler(i + 1);
}
```

Let's explain the code.

---

Basically, in this code, `makeHandler` is immediately executed each time we pass through the loop, each time receiving the then-current value of `i + 1` and binding it to a scoped `num` variable.

The outer function (`makeHandler`) returns the inner function (anonymous function) (which also uses this scoped `num` variable) and the element’s `onclick` is set to that inner function.

This ensures that each `onclick` receives and uses the proper `i` value (by the scoped `num` variable).

Answer (score 1):

change for var to let:

```
for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  elements[i].onclick = function () {
    console.log("This is element #" + i);
  };
}
```

Comment: A line of explanation about function scope and block scope would still be good.

Comment: Can you please explain why changing `var` to `let` works?

Comment: Read here: https://medium.com/@axionoso/watch-out-when-using-settimeout-in-for-loop-js-75a047e27a5f

Comment: `let` is better than `var` in terms of scope and optimization. Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let @Sagar